# APACHE Kudu does not natively support range deletes or updates

Tags: apache-kudu

Clarification requested on KUDU.

In the KUDU guides the following is stated:

Row delete and update operations must also specify the full primary key of the row to be changed. **Kudu does not natively support range deletes or updates**.

The first part makes sense. However, using IMPALA via Hue I can easily issue commands like these that relate to the highlighted part of the prose:

```
delete from metrics_001 where (value >= 400 and value <= 600); 

update metrics_001 set value = value + 1000 where (value >= 600 and value <= 800);
```

which execute as expected.

Does the statement mean that IMPALA allows this to be so? Could not find it from the documentation. I must be missing something elementary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Impala first scans Kudu for the records that meet the filter criteria, and then it sends back to Kudu the individual delete/update operations for each key that was found.

Comment: I see that it works as expected, but as a native English speaker I found it hard to follow. Your point is that underwater things are less optimal but it does work functionally. Gotcha